# Як перекласти useless?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Щоб описати ситуацію достатньо сказати "даремно".
Useful перекладається як "корисний", але "некорисний" чи "безкорисний" не означають "useless". Як сказати "he is useless for the project?"

Comment: Уточніть, будь ласка — вас цікавить саме прикметник? Бо якщо звичайний іменник також підходить, то «*нікчема/нездара*» вигладяють як гарні кандидати.

Comment: Саме прикметник. Це "useless". Воно "useless" для нашого проєкту. Нікчема не зовсім підходить у ці випадки, але це цікава альтернатива якщо описувати людей.

Comment: Впишіть, будь ласка, це уточнення у текст запитання (а коментарі видалимо). Бо переклади 'he is useless' та 'he is useless for the project' можуть відрізнятися, що продемонстровано в моєму коментарі. Для першого варіанту іменник годиться, для другого — ні.

Comment: Розширив приклад в питанні, дякую.

Comment: Він непридатний до цієї справи. Проект не отримує від нього жодної користі.

Answer (score 2):

Маємо три рівні:

1. Корисний.
2. Некорисний.
3. Шкідливий.

Тут *некорисний* точно відповідає англійському *useless*, бо так само охоплює нульово- і від'ємнокорисних.

Але є ще варіант [марний](http://sum.in.ua/s/marnyj):

> 2. Який не має істотного значення; незначний, пустий. ... Що я? Черв'як, **марная порошина**. Життя моє — листок, що ріс і зв'яв (Іван Франко, XIII, 1954, 325).

Отже можна сказати *він марний для нашої команди/проєкту.*

Comment: Дякую за відповідь! Некорисний більше звучить як "unhealthy", або "not beneficial", принаймні для мого вуха.

Зрозуміло що не всі англійські слова мають ідеальний прямий переклад, але "марний" -- це, здається, найближче за значенням слово яке може бути. Дякую.

Comment: Тут, відповідно до прикладу топікстартера useless - не корисний для проекту, якості якого неможна використати/долучити до проекту.

Answer (score 1):

Він нездалий для цього проєкту.
Джерело тлумачення:

> **НЕЗДАЛИЙ**, а, е, *діал*. Нездатний, невмілий. *Корови не злюбили нездалої доярки, що із штурханами, лайкою коло корів ходить* (Горд., Дівчина.., 1954, 204); // Бездарний, невдалий. *Крикуни.. в світ кричали: - Вірш, слізьми що напоєний, Є негарний і невдалий...* (Фр., XIII, 1954, 436); *Зачали панотці хвалитися, що нічого не читають. - І ця газета нездала, і та нездала, шкода часу!* (Март., Тв., 1954, 215).
> <sub>https://slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=нездалий</sub>

Comment: Діалектизм не може бути єдиною відповіддю. Спробуйте її розширити і відповідно до контексту навести декілька варіантів з синонімічного ряду.

Comment: Розширте відповідь адекватними обгрунтуваннями. Наразі вона рівноцінна "link-only" відповідям, що є причиною для рекомендації видалення.